# Bixby: Unable to get information after login with oAuth 2.0

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am able to login to my capsule referring the example of bank. I am unable to fetch the information i am looking for after login. There is some difference what I observe when comparing Bank with my capsule.

1: Once login is successful in Bank, I can see Bank Name in OAUTH section. Whereas When I logged in to my capsule successfully, nothing appear over there.

[image]

2: I am unable to fetch the information for user who logged in. Here are my code

**EndPoint**

```
endpoints {
    action-endpoints {
     action-endpoint (BookTicket){
       accepted-inputs (user_name,user_email,user_id)
       local-endpoint ("bookingticket.js")
       authorization {
         user
       }
    }
    action-endpoint (GetUserInfo){
     accepted-inputs(userInfo)
     local-endpoint ("GetUserInfo.js")
     authorization {
        user
     }
   }
 }
}
```

**Action**

```
action (BookTicket) {
  type(Search)
  collect {
    input (user_email) {
      type (UserEmail)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal { GetUserInfo }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  output (OrderBooking)
 }

 action (GetUserInfo) {
   type(Search)
   collect {
     input (userInfo) {
       type (UserInfo)
       min (Optional) max (One)
     }
   }
   output (InformaionUser)
 }
```

**Structure**

```
structure (InformaionUser){
  description (All the info regarding artist)
  property (userInfo){
    type (UserInfo)
    min (Required)
    max (One)
  }
}

structure (OrderBooking) {
   description(A transfer.)
   property (user_email){
     type (UserEmail)
     min (Required)
     max (One)
   }
}

structure (UserInfo) {
   description(A transfer.)
   property (user_email){
     type (UserEmail)
     min (Required)
     max (One)
   }
}

structure (UserEmail){
  role-of (InformaionUser)
}
```

After login i am redirected to simulator and the login page appears again. Debug is showing nothing. I am not sure what is wrong.

[image]

Comment: From my experience, when this kind of situation happens, its likely that OAuth call went through but did not succeed. Do you see any errors in the logs on the Provider side?

Comment: No, I checked bank capsule and the way it is returning response after login, my capsule is returning the same.

Comment: We need the information we asked from you to debug this effectively .. If you are concerned about lack of privacy on StackOverflow, please open a ticket with Bixby support to allow us to help you with this.

Comment: I have created one sample capsule for login part of my actual capsule. Is it fine?, if I submit diagnostic report from bixby simulator and you people would take a look on it?

Comment: Yes, the sample capsule would help us reproduce the situation but if you have the conversation id from the simulator, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Conversation ID: tr-20200317T172016.630Z-TOaNBQKS 
Also, I have shared the diagnostic report as well. Ticket (#4048)

Comment: I have opened another ticket. Please check #4051

Comment: is this still open? Are you guys working? Have figure out the issue and "invalid token" has gone now but still not able to went through the process. Providing the conversation ID: tr-20200401T142920.046Z-9IlZfpKhO
Let me know the issue please. Is there any way I can check the issue explanation through conversation ID.

Comment: kindly work through the ticket which is still open and pending your response. this is not a stackoverflow question

Comment: I have mail you guys in the mail chain... Still waiting for your response